# Protractor Get Text of Notification

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am testing part of our application which clears the cache for the user. Basically, the user clicks their user menu and then clicks the Clear Cache option. After this, a notification appears indicating that the cache has been cleared.

This option calls this method:

```js
        clearCache(): void {
            this.Cache.clearAll();
            this.localizedNotifications.notify('Cache cleared', 'info');
        }
```

My protractor test is:

```js
    it('Click Clear Cache from User Menu', () => {
      common.chooseUserMenuClearCache();
      let popUpAlert = browser.switchTo().alert();
      let alertText = popUpAlert.getText();
      expect(alertText).toMatch('Cache cleared');
    });
```

My test is returning that there is `no alert open`. This notification displays for a second or two and then disappears on its own. So I am wondering what I can do differently to get this test to pass?

Comment: The `browser.switchTo().alert();` handles a native window which doesn't seem to be the case here since it disappears on its own. Try to handle it as a web element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `browser.switchTo().alert()` I used `browser.switchTo().activeElement()` and it worked.